# Problem With CCMenuItem

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Iam trying to create simple menu according to the book CCMenuItem . here is my MenuView.m code 
bot nothing happens just a black screen appears ! without any menu !

iam working with COCOS2D 0.99.5

```
//
//  MenuView.m
//  Sence


#import "MenuView.h"
#import "HelloWorldScene.h"

@implementation MenuView

// in dastor hatman bayad dar menu badi neveshte shavad ke be onvane ye view shenasande shavad
+(id) scene
{
        CCScene* scene = [CCScene node];
        CCLayer* layer = [MenuView node];
        [scene addChild:layer];
        return scene;
}




-(id) init
{
        if ((self = [super init]))
        {
                CCLOG(@"init %@", self);

                // wait a short moment before creating the menu so we can see it scroll in
                [self schedule:@selector(createMenu:) interval:2];
        }
        return self;
}





- (void) menuItem1Touched {

        NSLog(@"test");
}


- (void) createMenu:(ccTime) delta {

 [self unschedule:_cmd];


        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        // set CCMenuItemFont default properties
        [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique"];
        [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:40];

        // create a few labels with text and selector
        CCMenuItemFont* item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Go Back!" target:self selector:@selector(menuItem1Touched:)];


        // create the menu using the items
        CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, nil];
        menu.position = CGPointMake(-(size.width / 2), size.height / 2);
        menu.tag = 100;
        [self addChild:menu];

        // calling one of the align methods is important, otherwise all labels will occupy the same location
        [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:40];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your this line:

```
CCMenuItemFont* item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Go Back!" target:self selector:@selector(menuItem1Touched:)];
```

should be

```
CCMenuItemFont* item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Go Back!" target:self selector:@selector(menuItem1Touched)];
```

Change from menuItem1Touched: to menuItem1Touched.. Remove the :

Tested and works..

Comment: I must consider about `:sender` and with out sender ! :D